# SQL Error: ORDER BY error on aggregating field,

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

I have a query that I keep receiving an error code of:

> Column "#t_APPS.DaysToDocs" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

with the following query. But I don't understand since the column is being aggregated (averaged) .. Help please.

```
SELECT TOP 80 PERCENT
    ta2.YoMo                    AS [YoMo]
    ,ta2.ProdCat_NID            AS [ProdCat_NID]
    ,ta2.AffilTXT               AS [AffilTXT]
    ,ISNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT ta2.AppDetID),-99) AS [NumDocsSentTop80]
    ,ISNULL(AVG(ta2.DaysToDocs*1.00),-999)*1.00  AS [eAvgDaysToDocsTop80]
FROM #t_APPS ta2
WHERE ta2.Rtype like 'DOCSSENT'
GROUP BY ta2.YoMo, ta2.ProdCat_NID, ta2.AffilTXT
ORDER BY ta2.DaysToDocs ASC
```

Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way for what I'm looking for. :/

I'm trying to get the Average of the best/top 80% of the DaysToDocs 
I thought by doing *Select top 80 percent [...] Order by DaysToDocs*  would give me the top 80%,  and the AVG(DaysToDocs) would then only average on that subset of records.

Comment: For what you want to do, you can get the top 80% in a derived table or CTE first, and then do your grouping and averaging on the results of that.

Answer (score 0):

Use ORDER BY ISNULL(AVG(ta2.DaysToDocs*1.00),-999)*1.00

or ORDER BY [eAvgDaysToDocsTop80]

That is what is in the select list and not the actual field

Comment: Thanks.
Would that change the results of what I'm looking for? 
maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree. 

I'm trying to get the Average of the best/top 80% of the DaysToDocs 
I thought by doing: Select top 80 percent [...] Order by DaysToDocs  would give me the top 80%,  and the AVG(DaysToDocs) would then only average on that subset of records.

Comment: I don't think that is going to work out like you think. The order by happens after the query is completed. If you want more complicated logic you need to look into the windowing/analytical functions. You can do some amazing calculations with those.. including exactly what you want https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the alias name, eAvgDaysToDocsTop80 in the order by. You can't order by the original table column, because you have calculated average of it.